# SmsManager.sendTextMessage from a BroadcastReceiver does nothing on CDMA phones

Tags: java, android, sms, cdma

I've got a BroadcastReceiver that handles the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` action, and sends a text message as a reply in certain cases. My app has the `android.permission.SEND_SMS`, and works fine on GSM phones. However, it doesn't work on the only CDMA phone I have available to me at the moment, and I suspect it only occurs on CDMA phones. It works on all of the GSM phones I have tried, which are quite a few. `logcat` shows no errors nor warnings, only `D/SMSSMSSMSSMS(  260): TeleService: 4098` each time `sendSms` is called. Furthermore, I have tried the exact same code in an Activity, and it works perfectly fine.

The code I'm using:

```
private void sendSms(String destination, String message) {
    if(preferencesManager.smsRepliesEnabled()) {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(destination, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

`preferencesManager.smsRepliesEnabled()` works as expected, and `destination` and `message` are set properly. I added a `Log.d` statement to confirm all three of these. Likewise, `PhoneNumberUtils.isWellFormedSmsAddress(destination)` returns `true`.

**EDIT**: On the advice of @wojci I added a `sentIntent` and logged the result code. The result code is `RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE`, with the extra `errorCode` set to `-1`. When I try the exact same code from an Activity, however, it works fine with `RESULT_OK`.

Comment: Is the message over 160 chars? Are there any unicode characters in the message? Some cdma networks don't like unicode, try converting to ASCII. Also, if it's a sprint phone with an integrated google voice number, there could possibly be strange issues there depending on phone/gv settings

Comment: The message is of variable length (but should never contain Unicode), but for testing I replaced it with a static four character string (`test`), and the same thing happened. It is a Sprint phone, but without GV integration. I had the GV app installed, but I also tried uninstalling it and rebooting without any effect.

Comment: Make sure you are importing `android.telephony.SmsManager` not `android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager`

Comment: I do indeed `import android.telephony.SmsManager;`. I target Jelly Bean, so I should get deprecation warnings, but I checked myself just in case.

Comment: Have you tried on different days? My Sprint phone will sometimes hold messages for a day or two before getting them all at once...

Comment: I have not, I just noticed this problem last night. To be honest, I'm only so eager to get this resolved quickly because I already have my app on Google Play, and I tested the latest Play release of my app, and it has the same problem on my phone. I'll give it a few days and see if I get spammed with a few dozen messages though.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, you should use a pending intent and check the returned result. It could be some network problem or limitation of which you have no knowledge unless you check the result of sending the sms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write that you use the following to send a text:
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(destination, null, message, null, null);

Why are you not using the [sentIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) parameter which can tell you if your message was accepted by the network?

From the documentation:

```
sentIntent  if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is successfully sent, or failed. The result code will be Activity.RESULT_OK for success, or one of these errors:
RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE
RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF
RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU
```

Maybe it can give you some more clues as to why your SMS sending does not work as you expect it to.

Comment: I haven't used `sentIntent` because my app won't work without receiving a text anyway, so the radio can't be off, but even if the message doesn't get sent, it doesn't change anything. My app works by taking action when you receive a text message with certain content, and the reply is purely advisory. At the moment, it just replies with a confirmation that the action requested was taken. But thanks, I'll try that out when I get a chance today.

Comment: I added `sentIntent`, and added a `Log.d` statement to log the results. About 30 seconds after the SMS is sent, it returns `RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE` with an `errorCode` of -1. Thanks! I tried looking, but I couldn't find any good reference; where can I find what `errorCode` -1 means on CDMA devices?

Comment: I suspect that this is just some generic error code from the modem. :(
Try looking at the output of "adb logcat -b radio" when you send the sms. Maybe it will tell you what at-commands are being used and what the result are. Maybe you get some useful info.

Comment: Yikes, that's a lot of logs. I don't see any AT commands, though. I see `D/RILC    (   70): [0444]> CDMA_SEND_SMS (uTeleserviceID=4098, bIsServicePresent=0, uServicecategory=0, sAddress.digit_mode=0, Address.Number_mode=0, sAddress.number_type=0, )`, followed by `D/RILC    (   70): [0445]> CDMA_SMS_ACKNOWLEDGE (uErrorClass=0, uTLStatus=0,)`, and finally `D/RILC    (   70): [0444]< CDMA_SEND_SMS {36,(null),-1} fails by E_GENERIC_FAILURE
D/RILJ    (  260): [0444]< RIL_REQUEST_CDMA_SEND_SMS error: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: GENERIC_FAILURE`. I don't see anything there. :(

Comment: What happens in the log when you manually send an SMS - does it work? If you compare the new log to the one you just captured - are there any settings which look like they could be wrong when your application sends the SMS?

Comment: I assume you're talking about from the stock Messaging app. I see `D/RILC (   70): [0468]< CDMA_SEND_SMS {38,(null),-1}`, followed by `D/RILJ (  260): [0468]< RIL_REQUEST_CDMA_SEND_SMS { messageRef = 38, errorCode = -1, ackPdu = null}`, then it broadcasting a PendingIntent, with `SMS send complete. Broadcasting intent:` and an instance of PendingIntent. Judging by the `RIL_REQUEST` bit, the `messageRef` when my app sends it is 36, but when I do it from Messaging, it's 38. That's the only difference I see, and I don't know if that's a random number or not. Doing it manually is much less spammy.

Comment: Oddly enough, I semi-isolated the problem. For some reason, it only happened when I texted my phone using (and it sent a reply to) my Google Voice number. As I said, I uninstalled the Google Voice app, so my phone and Google Voice weren't linked, but as soon as a tried from a "real" phone number it worked fine. I'm accepting your answer, as you helped with the troubleshooting. Thanks!